# Firefox stopped playing videos in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, firefox, video

I'm running Firefox 84.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.  Everything was working fine until a couple of weeks ago when Firefox just stopped being able to play videos.  It doesn't matter whether the site is YouTube or Crunchyroll, or what the format is.

If I visit a page with a video, for example a YouTube site, it spins and eventually tells me, "If this video doesn't play after a few seconds, try restarting your device."  In the console I see errors like `Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/webm; codecs="opus", video/mp4; codecs="av01.0.04M.08"` (or some other codec - it doesn't appear to matter what it is).

I've tried refreshing Firefox, launching under a new profile, clearing the cache (and cookies), installing/uninstalling/reinstalling ffmpeg and libavcodec, turning off "Play DRM protected content" between restarting firefox, launching in safe mode, and of course rebooting.  Nothing seems to work.

How do I get video playback to work again in Firefox?  Is there some log somewhere that will tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem sort of miraculously went away after copious amounts of `pulseaudio -k` at the terminal.  After doing that a dozen or so times, the problem almost disappeared; now when I see a video start to spin, I use that same command and the problem goes away.

Comment: +1, worked like a charm for me as well. I had a Bluetooth speaker which got disconnected after I ran that command once, and immediately I noticed the video back is fixed! after that I reconnected the speaker and all was fine. I guess this might have something to do with the drivers somehow messing up after some x amount of uptime (my machine is always on and running heavy processes (both cpu/gpu intensive) . 
Also I'm on 22.04 (upgraded from 20.04) to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

My firefox weren't playing videos (Ubuntu 20.4). I found this on google and worked:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

for the license use TAB and Enter

Answer (score 0):

For me killing `pulseaudio` didn't work, but killing `pipewire` and `pipewire-media-session` did.

Try if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Disable DRM / CDM plugging(s) and give it a shot, it worked for me (haven't watched videos on youtube before doing so though, so we might not share the same problem)